# I am doing an http request and am trying to store the data in a file, but the file is always empty, so why is this happening and how do I fix this?

Tags: dart, flutter

I am running an http request and the file is always empty. When I do this on android, it is always working fine, but when I do it on ios, it isn't working.

```
  http.Client client = new http.Client();
  var request = await client.get(Uri.parse(url));
  var bytes = request.bodyBytes;
  String dir = (await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path;
  File file = new File('$dir/$name');
  file.writeAsBytesSync(bytes);
  return file;
```

That is the code for the get request and returning the file. The file has the contents in my android device, but is null in ios. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Have you tried replacing `var bytes = request.bodyBytes;` with `var bytes = await request.bodyBytes;`?

Comment: `request.bodyBytes` isn't a future, so you can't `await` it.

Comment: Have you tried checking `request.statusCode` to see if there is some error?

Comment: I figured out that there was an error uploading, which caused an issue when downloading.